# Select only one (NOT TOP) record base upon desired data priority

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a sub-query that is part of a large query but really I think this problem is isolated to the subquery. If I am wrong however I will gladly post the entire thing.

I have records where a person may have 4 or 5 or 8 or 0 etc. entries. We want only one record but we have a preference. We'll take record B if record A isn't there etc.

Originally I was joining to the table

.....snip.....

```
LEFT JOIN [COMMUNICATION] Comm ON Peeps.PEOPLE_ID = Comm.PEOPLE_ID
```

and getting results such as

```
  ID      FIRST     LAST        ADDY     BIZ        CELL        FAX         HOME
21930   Person      Name        Addy    3237532500  NULL        NULL        NULL
21930   Person      Name        Addy    NULL        3237910815  NULL        NULL
21930   Person      Name        Addy    NULL        NULL        3235869055  NULL
21930   Person      Name        Addy    NULL        NULL        NULL        3238660704
21930   Person      Name        Addy    NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

In the communications table I really have 5 records so it is not a join issue.

Now I want only one row in this preference....
Home
Cell
Biz
Fax

So my first attempt was to do a subquery with TOP(1) but of course that only returns the top row of the table. I read on cte and am familiar with them but in this case I need to be able to join and not sure how you would 1. get the cte to order the records in the desired business priority and 2. how to join to it.

If you could just point my nose in the right direction or tell me what to study I will gladly do my own work.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have 5 rows for the same person? You will need to show your full query.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, this is what I came up to:

```
create table #temp_table (
    [id] int,
    [first] varchar(50),
    [last] varchar(50),
    [addy] varchar(50),
    [biz] varchar(50) null,
    [cell] varchar(50) null,
    [fax] varchar(50) null,
    [home] varchar(50) null 
)

insert into #temp_table
select 21930, 'Person', 'Name', 'Addy', '3237532500', null, null, null union all
select 21930, 'Person', 'Name', 'Addy', null, '3237910815', null, null union all
select 21930, 'Person', 'Name', 'Addy', null, null, '3235869055', null union all
select 21930, 'Person', 'Name', 'Addy', null, null, null, '3238660704' union all
select 21930, 'Person', 'Name', 'Addy', null, null, null, null


;with ordered as(
    select
        *,
        rn = row_number() over( partition by id 
                                order by 
                                    case
                                        when home is not null then 1
                                        when cell is not null then 2
                                        when biz is not null then 3
                                        when fax is not null then 4
                                        else 9999
                                    end
                               )
    from #temp_table 
)
select 
    [id],
    [first],
    [last],
    [addy],
    [biz],
    [cell],
    [fax],
    [home]
from ordered 
where 
    rn = 1

drop table #temp_table
```